# How to create database trigger to warn if some rows are not inserted yet?

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

How it is technically possible to create trigger to warn if there is now rows in other table at the same time when inserting data into another table?

I think BEFORE INSERT trigger does not work if there is nothing to compare at, right ?

Would it be then wise to create audit table where to insert something (some ID) first, using AFTER INSERT and THEN check with trigger and warn if rows missing from other table?

Could you provide some sample or easy explanation how to achieve this?
Interests me technically more than constraint options.

Thank you.

Comment: An example would be super helpful, i.e. here's table A, here's table B, if I insert this row of data into table A, I want X to happen because Y.  What does it mean to you to "warn" a user from a trigger?  Triggers can throw errors.  But there is no such thing as a runtime warning in PL/SQL.  And do you really mean "is now rows" rather than "is not rows"?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. First, sorry I wasn's specific enough. "Warn" means throw error. If inserting table A and there is nothing for that in table B, then throw error. These are :new records, so I cannot take value from table A before. I´m using Oracle 12 and noticed that there is new FOLLOWS enhancement which I understood that might help to combine triggers somehow...

Comment: I am confused-- why can't you use the `:new` pseudo-record?  That will certainly be available in a row-level trigger on A.  If you are trying to replicate the logic for a foreign key constraint using a trigger, why does that "interest you technically"?  A trigger based solution will be much slower, much less scalable, requires far more code, and is much more likely to have subtle bugs.  Plus it can't be used by the optimizer to do things like table elimination.  It's a wholly inferior technical solution.

Comment: Any chance to see sample or what you mean "pseudo-record"? Im really new with triggers, so that's why simple example might be helpful as well.

Comment: `:new` is a pseudo-record.  As is `:old`.  Any trigger that uses `:new.column_name` or `:old.column_name` is using the :new` and/or `:old` pseudo-record.  They're very similar to a `%rowtype` record defined in PL/SQL with the exception (in non-object tables) that they can't be passed as a parameter to another function.