# How to create trigger based on two joined tables and throw error if rows missing from third table?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have tables A, B and C.

A and B can be joined using unique ID
and C can be joined to B using another unique ID2.

Like

```
A.ID = B.ID
and B.ID = C.ID2
```

Now, I would like to have a trigger to check if there is record or not in C table during insert/update process in table A and throw error if not.

I´m using Oracle 12c, so more advanced options are also welcome.

Comment: In comments on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71017250/266304) you were told about `:new`, so have you tried to write trigger against A that queries B/C using `:new.id`? Please edit your question to include your table definitions, sample data, your attempt at writing the trigger and what issue you are having with it.

Comment: _"A and B can be joined using unique ID and C can be joined to B using another unique ID2."_,   And for what it's worth note that A and C can also be joined directly.  If A = B, and B = C, then it is also true that A = C.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to work the details, here is the general outline of what such a trigger would look like:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tablea_trg1
     AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
     ON tablea
 DECLARE
     l_cnt   INTEGER;
 BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT (*)     c
       INTO l_cnt
       FROM tablea
            INNER JOIN tableb ON tablea.abid = tableb.abid
            INNER JOIN tablec ON tableb.cid = tablec.cid
      WHERE tablea.abid = :new.abid;
 
     IF l_cnt = 0
     THEN
         raise_application_error (-2001, 'Boo boo happened');
     END IF;
 END;
```